# Internet drops frequently unless running an infinite ping

Tags: networking, internet, ping, isp

My internet tends to cut out and then return a few minutes later, I've been struggling with this issue for years with Comcast, I've gone through ~4 modems, and 2 routers and countless technician visits. 
It's not consistent in a way I can observe other than it happens daily, high or low traffic, hot or cold, night or day. I decided to start running a continuous ping to Google about a week or so ago just for kicks, and to my surprise, my internet stayed up and stable all day! I kept it running the next day, still up, and it has continued to stay up for the week or so I've been doing this. Just to check, I stopped the ping for a few hours and sure enough, internet cut out, I started it back up and it's been fine since, the only thing I can see still happening is that sometimes it gets extremely slow, but not completely out, so i can survive whatever the anomaly is this way. At this point I've ruled out hardware and software, pretty much everything, I wouldn't rule out a hardware or software issue, but itd be considerably coincidental. 
I'm fine with running a ping forever since its not exactly an expensive operation, but what I'd mainly like to know is what is causing this, and possibly asside from pinging, how to fix it? I've searched rather lightly on this, most results get poluted with questions about high ping and whatnot so even a search term would be useful so I could research this easier.

Comment: Sometimes connections on the Internet are created/maintained on an as-needed basis.  Probably bad that you can notice it, but not inconceivable that it happens.  See if you can get similar positive results by pinging some other IP address, like your computer's default gateway).  See if your modem/router supports logging in (maybe via HTTPS) and doing a(n infinite) ping test.  If so, that may be less burden on your LAN (computer CPU, switch bandwidth, etc.) and allow you to reboot/shutdown your computer, and not need to constantly see the reminder of the small cost.

Comment: @TOOGAM I'm running MTR in screen on my server, so it's not too big of a deal, I started of with a cronjob on router with 1 ping every 5 minutes and that did not solve the problem, continuous ping and/MTR put me where I am right now though. Speaking of said server, that's what made me notice the severity of it, not sure how it's been in the past few years, but for the past year and a halfish I've been running a home server with a bouncer and VPN, I've noticed the drops, I usually ping out of the irc servers I'm on multiple times a day, sometimes every few minutes or every hour at times.

Comment: @TOOGAM It's like the internet drops stack or something when I use ping, I changed mtr to go at my default gateway like you said, about 10 or so minutes later the internet dropped, now I'm back to pinging, yahoo is the 'victim' this time though and seems to be fine.

Comment: Nothing much more to update with this, still pinging and Internet is still up, still drops if I stop.

Comment: If the connection seems to "drop", what does that mean?  I assume you cannot ping Google/Yahoo/etc.  But can your computer ping it's default gateway?  Can your computer ping that device's default gateway?  What do the ARP tables show?  Such details may be needed to narrow this down further, and Comcast might need to provide some info and/or fix things themselves.  Whether that is required, or not, may depend on factors that cannot be determined just from the info that you have provided so far.

Comment: @TOOGAM If I can remember correctly from when I pointed mtr at the default gateway, I can't get past the router, so no to everything past the default gateway. As for with comcast, I'm about 80% sure there's a downstream issue with them, as other people on this street have similar issues, I just found it curious that it 'fixed' doing this and what that may have entailed.

Comment: I feel your pain: I frecuently use windows remote desktop to log in on a work computer where I do my work from home thru a VPN, and the only thing I've found that consistently avoids time-outs is running a cmd on my home PC with `ping google.com -t`, it's ridiculous.